# MySQL: Join two counts

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query provides the results I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `unique_id`, count(`unique_id`) AS TotalCount 
FROM `table1` 
GROUP BY `unique_id`;
```

It gives me the distinct unique_id column and a count, which is exactly the output I want.

```
Output:
unique_id | TotalCount
123       | 2
444       | 56
```

However, I have another table, which has less values then table1, but I want the same information from the query, meaning:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `unique_id`, count(`unique_id`) AS DifferentCount 
FROM `table2` 
GROUP BY `unique_id`;
```

Now I want to combine both queries into one, meaning, I want an output like:

```
Output:
unique_id | TotalCount | DifferentCount
123       | 2          | 1
444       | 56         | 30
```

How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `select distinct` with `group by`.  It is very, very rarely the right thing to use.

I would recommend doing:

```
select unique_id, sum(cnt1) as cnt1, sum(cnt2) as cnt2
from ((select unique_id, count(*) as cnt1, 0 as cnt2
       from table1
       group by unique_id
      ) union all
      (select unique_id, 0 as cnt1, count(*) as cnt2
       from table2
       group by unique_id
      )
     ) t12
group by unique_id;
```

This will ensure that you get all ids from both tables.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I'm quite confused on the "t12" part though, what is it doing?

Comment: @OldMcDonald . . . `t12` is a table alias for the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
select uid, count(itm1) cnt1, count(itm2) cnt2 from
( select unique_id uid, 1 itm1, null itm2 from table1
  union all
  select unique_id, null, 1 from table2 ) both
group by uid
```